# Creating Nested JSON in Android

Tags: java, android, json

Say I want to make the following JSON

```
{
    "key" : "1234",
    "request" : "info",
    "info" : {
        "type" : "user",
        "login" : {
            "username" : "some_username",
            "password" : "some_password"
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, this is how I'm achieving it

```
//Construct the JSON
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONObject info_json = new JSONObject();
JSONObject login_info = new JSONObject();           
try
{
    login_info.put("username", "some_username");
    login_info.put("password", "some_password");

    info_json.put("type", "user");
    info_json.put("login", login_info);

    json.put("key", "1234");
    json.put("request", "info");
    json.put("info", info_json);
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();  
    System.out.println("JSON could not be made");
}
```

It seems there should be a better way of doing this instead of making more `JSONObjects`, and placing them in a main `JSON Object`.  Is there a better way to construct these on the fly than the method I am using?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Frankly, for something this simple, I don't even bother using the JSON classes and just print the json straight to stdout (or wherever your destination is).

Comment: [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is the answer.

Comment: you could just load it as one String.

Comment: Well, my use case isn't always this simple, just wanted a simple example on here instead of having a 300 line example of nested `JSONObjects` @Edward Falk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work a lot with JSON data I would really recommend that you use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). It's a lot more convenient and both of the libraries have very good support for converting to and from Java objects (which is a lot less messy and error prone than manually building your JSON through JSONObjects).

Comment: IMHO I've found Gson to be very easy to use

Comment: Gson and Jackson are very similar in functionality and they're almost interchangeable.