# How to create JSON in Android

Tags: android, json

How do I create nested JSON in Android. The JSON data should look like this :

```
JSON
Customername = Roshan
Customercode = 100
Customercity = Ernakulam
Customerstate = Kerala
Customercountry = India
Customersales
    Productname = Biscuit
    Productcode = 123
    Producttype = Food
Customersales
    Productname = Shoes
    Productcode = 234
    Producttype = Dress
```

Note : I was able to create JSON without nesting, but I am not able to create nested JSON data. How do we do this ?

Comment: If u have tried anything then please post it.

Comment: Use Gson OR Jakson. :) :)

Comment: Use jackson for that!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Nested JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286902/creating-nested-json-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I wrote the code you wanted. I hope it be useful for others too.

```
    TextView testText;
    testText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testText);

    JSONObject customer,customerSales;
    JSONArray customers;
    List<JSONObject> productList;


    //Populate 4 Customers information for test
    customers = new JSONArray();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            //create new customer
            customer = new JSONObject();
            customer.put("Customername", "name "+(i+1));
            customer.put("Customercode", 100+i+1);
            customer.put("Customercity", "city "+(i+1));
            customer.put("Customerstate", "state "+(i+1));
            customer.put("Customercountry", "country "+(i+1));

            //Add 3 Product Sales for each customer
            productList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                customerSales = new JSONObject();
                customerSales.put("Productname", "Product name "+(j+1));
                customerSales.put("Productcode", 200+j+1);
                customerSales.put("Producttype", "Product type "+(j+1));
                productList.add(customerSales);
            }

            customer.put("Customersales", productList);
            customers.put(customer);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Access Customers information
        try {
                testText.setText("");
            for (int i = 0; i < customers.length(); i++) {

                testText.append("Costumer number "+ (i+1) + ":\n");
                testText.append("    Customer Name:"+customers.getJSONObject(i).getString("Customername"));
                testText.append("\n");
                testText.append("    Customer Code:"+customers.getJSONObject(i).getInt("Customercode")+"");
                testText.append("\n");
                testText.append("    Customer City:"+customers.getJSONObject(i).getString("Customercity"));
                testText.append("\n");
                testText.append("    Customer State:"+customers.getJSONObject(i).getString("Customerstate"));
                testText.append("\n");
                testText.append("    Customer Country:"+customers.getJSONObject(i).getString("Customercountry"));
                testText.append("\n    Sales for this Customer:\n");

                JSONArray tmpArray = new JSONArray(customers.getJSONObject(i).getString("Customersales"));


                for (int j = 0; j < tmpArray.length(); j++) {
                    testText.append("        Product number "+(j+1)+":\n");         
                    testText.append("            Product Name:"+tmpArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("Productname"));
                    testText.append("\n");
                    testText.append("            Product Code:"+tmpArray.getJSONObject(j).getInt("Productcode")+"");
                    testText.append("\n");
                    testText.append("            Product Type:"+tmpArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("Producttype"));
                    testText.append("\n");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thank You for this. This worked out, but there is a small problem. For each internal JSON, each double quotes(") is represented like this \" . So, when I send the data to the server via fiddler, the child array is not being inserted.

How to corect this ?

Comment: what?!! what is fiddler?? why don't you simply use loopj's [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)?
even Instagram and Pinterest are using it. it's so simple.

Comment: you asked how to create nested json. so this is your answer, if you want to know how to handle the json you sent on the server, you should search or ask for that somewhere else.

Comment: send the customers.toString() as a parameter with loopj's library.
then in the server get them in php like this:
                                                                     
if (isset($_POST['test']))  {
  $contents = $_POST['test'];
  $contents = utf8_encode($contents);
  $contents = json_decode($contents, true);
  if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
   echo "ready\n";
   echo $contents[0]["Customername"];
  } else {
   echo "not ready";
  } 
  
 }

Answer (score 1):

You would work with JSONObject.

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Create a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
```

Add element:

```
json.accumulate(key,value);
```

Get a JSON:

```
json.toString;
```