# Pass an object containing key value pairs, as a value to a hashmap in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap, android-volley

I am using **Volley Library** to post in android for which I do this

```
JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(hashMap));
```

Here in the second parameter of the new JsonObjectRequest I am converting the hashmap into an JSONObject.

Below is my hashMap

```
 Map<String, Object> postparams = new HashMap<String, Object>()
        postparams.put("protocol", "A");
        postparams.put("service_type", "B");
        postparams.put("access_id",accessID);
        postparams.put("contact", contactDetails);
```

The contact key has a nested JSON as a value like this

> contact : 
>               { contactName: "ABCD", phoneNumber: "98980980980" }

How can do I do this?

**My Attempt :** I tried creating a hashmap and converting it with jackson and pass it but I got an error which is expected as I am converting an object to JSON twice.

Comment: And you should check the correct variable you want to post is `hashMap` or `postparams` :)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo i have edited it. Thanks for the comment . @BNK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `contact` key value is:

```
{ contactName: "ABCD", phoneNumber: "98980980980" }
```

means want to pass a JSONObject which contains `contactName` and `phoneNumber` as key value pair :

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
json.put("contactName", contactDetails.getcontactName());
json.put("phoneNumber", contactDetails.getphoneNumber());

...
postparams.put("contact", json.toString());
```

Comment: Q: Are you talking about the standard Android library's [org.json.JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)?

Comment: In that case - thumbs up.  An excellent suggestion.  Simply using Android Json library is simple, efficient ... and *much* easier than trying to wrestle with Jackson.  PS: a JSONObject *is* basically just a Java hashmap ... but it's easy to nest objects within objects as much as you need to.  It's also easy to serialize/deserialize between Java objects and JSON text.

Comment: Hi guys thank you for your suggestions/solution, it looks like this should work , although i am not able to verify if today as its weekend here and the servers are off,  I will surely get back with the results once i test it on Monday. Cheers @paulsm4 @K (I am sorry not able to type your full user name)

Comment: Thank you @K for the suggestion for using JSONObject as it really simplified the task. For those who are just reading this this link helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286902/creating-nested-json-in-android

Comment: Is their any automatically way to achieve the above ?.. Meaning Object only ?